# Installation for SQLAlchemy Doesn't link to Flask

Tags: python-2.7, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to install SQLAlchemy on a Windows 8 64 bit machine for Python 2.7

When I run the setup.py file that comes with the download from the SQLAlchemy site, a .egg file called 'SQLAlchemy-1.0.0-py2.7.egg' is placed in C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages.

But when I try to do a basic import of the library using an import statement on given in the SQLAlchemy documentation, I get an error message.

The import code is:

```
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
```

And the error message I get is:

```
c:\Users\Me\MyCode>ws_dbwrite.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Me\MyCode\ws_dbwrite.py", line 2, in <module>
    from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask-0.10.1-py2.7.egg\flask\exthook.py",
line 87, in load_module
    raise ImportError('No module named %s' % fullname)
ImportError: No module named flask.ext.sqlalchemy
```

Should I be going about installation in a different manner? Or should the .egg file for SQLAlchemy go at a different file level? Or am I missing something obvious here?

Edit: If I change the import line to just

```
import SQLAlchemy
```

The import works, but Python does not recognize things like

```
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

as valid commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have installed SQLAlchemy, but you are trying to use the Flask extension, [Flask-SQLAlchemy](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/). While the two are related, they are separate libraries. In order to use

```
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
```

you need to install it first.

```
pip install Flask-SQLAlchemy
```

(You installed SQLAlchemy directly from source. You can also do that for Flask-SQLAlchemy.)